# What are MIPS coprocessor 1 a nd coprocessor 0 used for?

Tags: mips, mips32

I am totally new to MIPS and I was wondering the difference between the Registers and Coproc 1 and Coproc 0. 
I know the registers, they are used to save data in them, how about these coprocs?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coprocessor 0 is for [exception handling](http://www.it.uu.se/education/course/homepage/os/vt18/module-1/mips-coprocessor-0/).

Coprocessor 1 used to be for floating point arithmetic on old MIPS CPUs. I don't know if it's used for anything on newer revisions.